# Email of older svn commits using commit-email.pl

Tags: svn, email, commit

Due to some issues with our mailserver we have lost a few `svn commit` emails.

Is there a way to manually send emails for those missed svn commits?

I tried the following

```
COMMIT_EMAIL="/usr/share/doc/subversion-1.6.11/tools/hook-scripts/commit-email.pl"
perl  $COMMIT_EMAIL --revprop-change <REPO> <REV> test test --from svnadmin@example.com -r recipient@example.com
```

But this returns 0 exit code and emails are not getting triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For commit emails you should just be able to run the hook script itself manually:

```
/path/to/repo/hooks/post-commit /path/to/repo revnum
```

Comment: The same command `perl  $COMMIT_EMAIL <REPO> <REV> --from svnadmin@example.com -r recipient@example.com` is there in the post-commit script with variables REPO and REV getting values from arguments. I ran that command too and that too returns 0 exit code without triggering email.

Comment: It did worked problem was the to email was not getting passed properly. Proper arguments to the script that worked was `perl $COMMIT_EMAIL <REPO> <REV> --from svnadmin@example.com -r reply-to@example.com recipient@example.com`